# Maven JIB returns "CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed" inside arm32v7/adoptopenjdk docker container

Tags: java, maven, docker, jib, adoptopenjdk

I am using my raspberry pi 4 with Docker installed. I am trying to create a build container for my Java projects and let the build container create Docker images using [Maven JIB](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin). When I try this in an [arm32v7/adoptopenjdk:13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-bionic](https://hub.docker.com/layers/arm32v7/adoptopenjdk/13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot/images/sha256-95f5dacc4c3c997c0428fa0a315346c88e0b02899d46ae7c990daeda24ce5136) container, JIB gives the following error:

```
[ERROR] I/O error for image [registry-1.docker.io/arm32v7/adoptopenjdk]:
[ERROR]     PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
```

When I try the same setup in an Ubuntu virtual machine on my laptop, with Docker installed and with an [openjdk:13-jdk](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/13-jdk/images/sha256-e318b76728d5f2a1864717cbe23376bea1ea19dd29f157430a1b379a842e6b6e) container, it succeeds.

I am trying to build a simple [spring initialzr](https://start.spring.io/) java project with JIB as a build plugin. The build tag in my pom.xml looks like the following:

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
  <finalName>thaveke-backend</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <from>
          <image>arm32v7/adoptopenjdk:13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-bionic</image>
        </from>
        <to>
          <image>backend</image>
        </to>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>dockerBuild</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Because of the PKIX error I immediately thought of an outdated cacerts so I copied the cacerts file from the [openjdk:13-jdk](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/13-jdk/images/sha256-e318b76728d5f2a1864717cbe23376bea1ea19dd29f157430a1b379a842e6b6e) container where it did work, to the [arm32v7/adoptopenjdk:13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-bionic](https://hub.docker.com/layers/arm32v7/adoptopenjdk/13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot/images/sha256-95f5dacc4c3c997c0428fa0a315346c88e0b02899d46ae7c990daeda24ce5136) container and ran the maven command but still received the same error.

If you have a raspberry pi 4 with Debian Buster OS, this error is reproducable using the following steps:

1. Install docker using following commmand: `curl https://get.docker.com | sh`
2. Create a simple [spring initialzr](https://start.spring.io/) project and unpack it on the raspberry pi. update the build tag in the pom.xml file to look like mine above. In my case the unpacked updated code is under /opt/app.
3. Run a docker container and go into a bash terminal using following command: 
   `docker run --rm -it -v /opt/app:/opt/app -v /var/run/
   docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):$(which docker) arm32v7/adoptope
   njdk:13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-bionic bash`
4. When inside the docker container, change directory to /opt/app: `cd /opt/app`
5. Run maven command to compile and build docker image: `./mvnw clean package -DskipTests`

I am not sure if this is a JIB error, an AdoptOpenJDK error or am I just overlooking something?

Kind regards

Comment: `docker run --rm -it ... arm32v7/adoptopenjdk:13.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-bionic` will give you a jshell prompt. (Run `jshell` manually if you just get a sh prompt.) On jshell, try `new URL("https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/").openStream()` to see if it still returns PKIX error. (OTOH, getting 401 is expected.) If it doesn't work, it's some cert issue on the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something very similar with running adoptopenjdk on the raspberry pi inside a jib docker image. this [issue](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/676) seemed somewhat related. I ended up using a [different jdk from bellsoft](https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine/tags). I was using the gradle jib instead of the maven plugin but it should work the same. Good luck.

```
from {
  // https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2148
  image = "bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine@sha256:91a5cede9b201c98ef6fc13aff270f58f07bee86ed9f508e22c7a883bfef2679"
}
```